# Hide user id in the url bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, header

In my rails application I currently have a load of users who each have a registered user id.

If I go in to my users index and click on a users show page I get the following example header.

localhost:3000/users/3

Now I don't like this as it easily allows people to skip through users in the header.

How would I go about doing the following so that it shows the user.username field instead e.g.

localhost:3000/users/adamwest

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define a `to_param` method on the User model.

```
class User
  ...
  def to_param
    name
  end
  ...
end
```

Then every generated URLs will have `name` instead of `id` as a user identifier.

```
sid = User.new :name => 'sid'
user_path(sid) #=> "/users/sid"
```

Of course, in the controller, you have to find user by name.

```
class UsersController
  ...
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_name(params[:id])
  end
  ...
end
```

I also suggest you to take a look at [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem.

> FriendlyId is the “Swiss Army bulldozer” of slugging and permalink
>   plugins for ActiveRecord. It allows you to create pretty URL’s and
>   work with human-friendly strings as if they were numeric ids for
>   ActiveRecord models.

Comment: Thanks for that, works great. I have set it to the basic for now but will check out this friendly_id gem in order to create a more friendly site. Thanks.

Comment: And if `User#name` can contain a period then you'll want `:constraints => { :name => /.*/ }` on the route to keep Rails from trying to interpret the stuff after the period as a format.