# Hide id from url in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to rails. I have developed an application on rails recently. The application is pretty big and it's running fine. Currently i have url like this.

```
http://192.168.99.220/user/13/domainUsers
```

I want it to be like the below one (without any id)

```
http://192.168.99.220/user/domainUsers
```

My routes are like this.

```
match 'user/:id/domainUsers', :to => 'domains#manageDomain_2', :as => :manageDomain2
```

I have tried to rewrite the url using "to_param". As my application is too big and it has lots of functionalities, i am using parameters other than the "id" to find users informations frequently, so i am not being able to use the "to_param" method. Is there any other way to hide "id" from url.

Please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of a similar question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623017/hide-user-id-in-the-url-bar]

Comment: i have gone through that question, it doesn't suite my requirement, i am not being able to use "to_param" as i am not using "id" to find my users always. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is with a gem called friendly_id.

Here is a tutorial that explains it quite well:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid